# The importance of the features for a logistic regression model

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I have a traditional logistic regression model.

I want to know how I can use `coef_` parameter to evaluate which features are important for positive and negative classes. Some of the values are negative while others are positive. Does it mean the lowest negative is important for making decision of an example as a negative class? I don't know about it. One more thing, how can I convert those values to standardized regression coefficients?

I will appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "important." The "Race of Variables" section of [Gary King, "How Not to Lie with Statistics" (1985)](http://gking.harvard.edu/files/mist.pdf) makes some useful observations. Even on a standardized scale, coefficient magnitude is not necessarily the correct way to assess variable importance. Standardized variables are not inherently easier to interpret.

Coefficients in logistic regression have the same interpretation as they do in OLS regression, except that they are under a transformation $g : \mathbb{R}\to(0,1).$ This transformation is sigmoidal, so how far you "move" given a change in the input depends on where you were at the start. Negative coefficients mean that one, on average, moves the prediction closer to being a negative example. Positive coefficients move on closer to being classified as a positive example, on average.

How to compute standardized variables (and the reverse) has been answered before, and I'm searching for the post right now.

Comment: I also searched how to compute standardized variables on this web site, but I couldn't find it. If you did, please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: @mgokhanbakal I've found the relevant page for the reverse. But to compute standardized coefficients, just standardize your data, then run the regression.